# Find intersection point of two lines in 3D

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, 3d

I need to find the intersection for the following two lines:

- $[x,y,z] = [2,-1,3]+k_1[1,2,3]$ and $[x,y,z] = [5,1,4]+k_2[3,2,1]$

So my approach is to find the intersection using gaussian elimination:

- $$
  \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c}
  2+k_1=5+3k_2 \\ 
  -1+2k_1=1+2k_2 \\ 
  3+3k_1=4+k_2
  \end{array}
  \right. 
  $$
- $$
  \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{c}
  3+3k_2=k_1 \\ 
  2+2k_2=2k_1 \\ 
  1+k_2=3k_1
  \end{array}
  \right. 
  $$
- $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{cc|c}
    3&3&1\\
    2&2&2\\
    1&1&3
  \end{array}
  \right] $$
- And the result matrix I obtained is:
  $$ \left[
  \begin{array}{cc|c}
   1&1&\frac{1}{3}\\
    0&0&1\\
    0&0&0
  \end{array}
  \right] $$

This is where the problem appears, I am not sure what value should I give for $k_1$ and $k_2$.

However, the answer key says the intersection is $(2,-1,3)$. Can anyone tell me where I did wrong?

Comment: when $k_1=0$ and $k_2=-1$, the point is $(2,-1,3)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}3+3k_2=3k_1\\2+2k_2=2k_1\\1+k_2=3k_1,\end{array}\right.$$you should turn it into$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3k_1+3k_2=-3\\-2k_1+2k_2=-2\\-3k_1+k_2=-1.\end{array}\right.$$The second equation is redundant, since it is the first one times $\frac23$. So, consider just the system$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}-3k_1+3k_2=-3\\-3k_1+k_2=-1.\end{array}\right.$$Its only solution is $(k_1,k_2)=(0,-1)$. And then you will get that the intersection point is $(2,-1,3)$ (and not $(2,1,3)$).

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that I have to put all variables on one side! Thank you for correcting me!

Answer (score 1):

When you’ve performed Gaussian elimination in the past, did you create the augmented matrix from a system of equations that had variables on both sides of the equations? Move all of the variables to the same side first. The resulting reduced matrix should make more sense.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I just realized. I have no idea how can I did not notice that despite checking for many times over